# replacing lamp post; can underground electrical wire be in concrete?

Tags: electrical, concrete, backyard

I'm replacing an old lamp post. Am digging out the old one. The wire seems to be at least or around a foot down, instead of a few inches. I'm not sure if the old pole had a hole in the side, about 12-15 inches from the bottom, like the new one does. It looks like the cable came in from the bottom, maybe.

My main question is, can the electrical cable be in concrete? The instructions indicate it's not supposed to, you're supposed to run the cable into a hole in the new pole, which is about 12-15 inches from the bottom, then fill the hole up to just below that hole and cable. But with the cable being so far down, I'd have to dig a much deeper hole, in order to keep it out of the concrete.

Sorry if I don't know right terms. The electrical wire is Romex, I believe. It is not in any additional conduit, just the white sheathing. I don't know about the pole entry hole and conduit fittings.

There is no current concrete, so the depth of the concrete is as deep as I'll dig. Looks like I'll have to go more like 18-24" down to get enough depth of concrete to stay below the wire, which is about 12" below ground.

Unless I do what a buddy just told me: just keep the wire clear, fill the concrete with the post in it until below the side hole in the post, let it cure, and then run the wire up the side of the concrete and then bend it over the top of the concrete and into the side hole in the pole.

Comment: Cable in conduit with concrete around the conduit is good.

Comment: A few things need clarification, which you can do by editing the question: Is it direct bury cable, not in conduit?  How deep is the bottom of the concrete, and how far below or above ground is the top of it?   How far below or above ground is the entry hole in the pole?  Is the entry hole suitable for attaching typical conduit fittings?

Comment: thanks, I tried to add more info in the post

Comment: If it is romex then the whole cable will need replacing.  Romex/NM-b cannot be outside of the house.  You need UF/direct bury/wet proof conduit wires.  Romex insulation breaks down when outside/in wet conditions.